# How to create a multi-content page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a multi individual post but I can't find way to do it. I'm using a theme called *zerif-lite* and I have two custom menus - *Our Client* and *Carreers*. For *Carreers* I use a plugin called *Job Manager*.

When I click a link on either menu, it goes to the template `Content-page.php`, whereas I want the links from the *Carreers* menu to go to a page using the `Carrers-page.php template`.

You can see in my picture the result that I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good approach would be to include your requird file carres-page.php.

You can do this like below:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/carres-page.php' ); ?>
```

Comment: many error , do u have another way for me ?

Comment: error it should not be, what's error and did you include  file properly

Comment: First I create carres-page.php then I pass ur code

Comment: then you can use this <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>  to learn more about it you can it on https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: And why I can not ask more question, maby they block my acc :(

Comment: No, You can ask as many as you want...but questions should be practically possible and logical...